# Add Google Licensing Validation (LVL) Check in an Application made with Appcelerator

Tags: android, google-play, appcelerator, licensing, android-lvl

I've been trying to attach the Google Licensing Validation Check (https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html) to my application made with Appcelerator. I found a GIT repository (https://github.com/eric-sofisoftwarellc/TiLicensing) that was supposed to contain a module that would do the job, but there is no .ZIP file in there, so the instructions are either incomplete or unclear.

I have tried to add the source files into the "modules" folder of my application, but it displays this error:

```
ti:/module.js:280: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: com.sofisoftwarellc.licensechecker.
```

I also found this question ([How to add Google Play license into an android application created with Appcelerator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036223/how-to-add-google-play-license-into-an-android-application-created-with-appceler)), that redirected me to the same repository in the end.

Does someone have the .zip file that is specified in the instructions of the GIT repository or has someone ever made it work? I've tried building the module with Appcelerator Studio, but it did not work.

Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in a Titanum SDK 6+ project you have to recompile the module because it was created 2 years ago. But that won't work that easily because it is using some legacy classes (org.apache.http) so you have to change the module in order to get it to work, sorry.